# Advice with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

Need help with regular expression. I have tried with a cheat sheat but it won't work.
I am looping through lines from a List and are looking for a match:

```
mail exchanger = *.domain.com
```

Where * = everything.

Any help on that?

I have tried with:

```
\\w[mail exchanger = ].*\\.domain\\.com
```

- But it also matches on line without the "exchanger" part in it.

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to provide more detail on the problem that you are having and why the solutions that you have tried so far aren't working before other people are going to be able to help out.

Comment: *\.domain\.com * because "." is single character and "\." is "."

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question :)

Comment: You need to edit again, clearly showing what you are trying to match and what you are trying to *not* match (using `<pre>`…`</pre>` to get fixed layout without syntax highlighting. Also `Where * = everything` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `line.Contains(".domain.com") && line.Contains("mail exchanger = ")`?  Nice and simple.

---

Your regular expression isn't working because the `[]`'s say to match *any* character in them.  So it will match an `m`, an `a`, an `i`, and so on... You mean to use `()`'s.

Comment: Because then I will get output from lines that I am not interrested in. I need this one line (output from nslookup)

Comment: @user1281991 - Edited my answer to account for your edits.  I'd suggest not using regular expressions, but if you want to, I have a fix for that, too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice way to use line.Contains. But I ended up with the Regex with ()'s and it works perfectly. Thank you very much. Don't know why I have gotten all the "downs" though.

Comment: @user1281991 - Mostly, the question wasn't very clear in it's original form. It's better now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing wildcards with regex. The Regex in this case would be something like:

`^.+?\.domain\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`.[a-zA-Z0-9]*.com`